# Using WWW::Mechanize to navigate forms on Amazon site

Tags: perl

I am using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to automatically add my email address as a preferred one. After a lot of difficulty I could log into the page, but when I try to add an email address as an allowed email address it does not work. Even the link does not show up. What am I doing wrong? The link of the Amazon page is [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&%2aVersion%2a=1&%2aentries%2a=0#pdocSettings).

My code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTML::Form;
use WWW::Mechanize::Link;

my $bot = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$bot->agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla' );

$bot->cookie_jar( HTTP::Cookies->new(file           => "cookies.txt",
                                     autosave       => 1,
                                     ignore_discard => 1, ) );
# Connect to the login page
my $response = $bot->get( 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html/' );

# Get the login form. You might need to change the number.
$bot->form_number(3);

# Enter the login credentials.
$bot->field( email => 'email' );
$bot->field( password => 'pass' );
$response = $bot->click();

#print $response->decoded_content;
$bot->get( 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0#pdocSettings' );
my @links = $bot->find_all_links( tag => "a" );

foreach (@links)
{
  print $_->text()."\n" ;
}
```

My tamper data is this

```
Referer=https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&%2AVersion%2A=1&%2Aentries%2A=0

POSTDATA=sid=183-7190983-6755358&newEmail=myid%40mailhost.com
```

Edit:  After searching I realised that `WWW::Mechanize` may not be able to achieve this as it lacks JavaScript support. I decided to use [`WWW::Scripter`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aScripter) with the plugin. Would someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: hmm.. i think, that CPAN can give you Amazon modules, are you search something similar?

Comment: I could not find one to allow me to add a email address to a particular account.

Comment: That link goes to the Kindle library page of *Your Account* on Amazon.com. Did you want to *change* the email address assigned to your account? Amazon allows only one per account and I don't understand wanting to automate changing it.

Comment: The requirement is as a part of another program that others will use. It is to save them from the trouble of doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found answer to your question on other post: [Calling a link from perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646505/calling-a-link-from-perl/10653681#10653681)

For future tasks similar to this one, I suggest you to do following work-around:

- install Google Chrome (if you don't have it already)
- navigate browser to form page you want to simulate
- on submit button click right-click mouse button and select *"Inspect element"*
- switch to *"Network"* tab
- click to submit button on the form
- see information in *"Network"* table, especially in *"Headers"* and *"Response"* sub-tabs.

By this kind of debugging you will find exact communication between server and browser, including cookies, referers, request methods, urls, submit data, etc.

Comment: I realised that -Only difference i did it with firebug in firefox. Thanks for the response anyway