# Calling a link from perl

Tags: perl

I am using WWW::Scripter to call a javascript. The link to the site is [this.](https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk#pdocSettings)
The html of the document looks like this.

```
<form id="whitelistForm" method="get" action="">
<table id="whitelistTable" class="info">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="firstCol" width="75%" style=""> E-mail address </th>
<th class="lastCol">Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>id@mailhost.com</td>
<td class="button">
<a onclick="deleteWhitelist('id@mailhost.com')" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="whitelist-du-output" class="actionResult"></div>
<div class="subLink">
<a id="addNewEmailAddress" class="myk-link" href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-weight: normal;"> Add a new approved e-mail address </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to execute addNewEmailAddress from perl .(I have already logged in using WWW::Mechanize).

Comment: If you want to follow a link you need to use follow_link of www::mechanize ..Refer to this link for details  http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Efollow_link%28...%29

Comment: I have tried that and even find_all_links but it does not show up. Probably because the add new email address is a javascript

Comment: Got your point. Can you check this link which says something about Javascript link http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Shell-0.52/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Shell.pm.  Sorry,if the link is not useful

Comment: You can't execute `addNewEmailAddress` because that is an [HTML id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id), not a JavaScript expression. -- Clarify: is the code you posted really the serialised DOM as returned from **Scripter**'s `content` method?

Comment: I get it. But i used firebug and this was what was printed. I really dont get how it works. Even the href does not point to an actual link. Once again the site is https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk#pdocSettings

Comment: Look at the DOM generated by WWW::Scripter, obviously there is an event attached to that `a` element. Learn about JS event handlers. - It makes no sense to post a link to a password-protected page. If you want people to help you, you must enable them to see the problem on their own. Either [reduce all HTML and JS until you have a minimal test-case](http://sscce.org), or give us everything as stand-alone files to [reproduce the functionality of that page off-line](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow), or with Amazon's permission give credentials for a test account.

Comment: I am sorry but i thought if you had a amazon account you could login.Wont happen anymore.I took a different approach to this problem. I simply copied the headers generated in my firefox extension and try to replicate them. But i dont know how exactly to do that. I have posted a question.-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648754/how-do-i-simulate-this-particular-post-request-in-mechanize. Just as an addon- How do i look at the dom generated by the www::scripter. As when i used firebug i could not see it override onclick or any other event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Perl to add/submit (new) email address to this Amazon system, you have to first log in.

I believe that step you have already coded. Then you have to **save cookies** for further requests.

---

To submit email you need to call **POST** request to url:

`https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/du/add-whitelist.html/ref=kinw_myk_wl_add`

and submit two parameters with this request:

- **sid** *(this is a session id you will find in cookies; example: 183-9522205-2962863)*
- **newEmail** *(email address you want to submit; example: my@email.address.com)*

Do not forget to encode those strings.

Check response code, has to be **200**. Then read response text to check a value of **success** parameter.

You may need to **add referer** to this request. If so, then it should be:

`https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk`