# How do i simulate this particular post request in mechanize

Tags: perl

The post request is as follows.

```
 $bot->add_header(
'Host'=>'www.amazon.com',
'User-Agent'=>'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
'Accept'=>'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
'Accept Language'=>'en-us,en;q=0.5',
'Accept Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate',
'DNT'=>'1',
'Connection'=>'keep-alive',
'Content type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'X-Requested with'=>'XMLHttpRequest',
'Referer'=>'https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk',
'Content length'=>'44',
'Cookie'=>'how do i put the cookie value');




Post parameters in my request :
sid-how do i get the session id.
new email-mailhost@mail.com
```

My code to logon:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTML::Form;
use WWW::Mechanize::Link;
my $bot = WWW::Mechanize->new();
 $bot->agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla' );
 # Create a cookie jar for the login credentials
 $bot->cookie_jar(         HTTP::Cookies->new(             file           => "cookies.txt",
                                              autosave       => 1,
                                              ignore_discard => 1,     ) );
 # Connect to the login page
 my $response = $bot->get( 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html/' );
 # Get the login form. You might need to change the number.
 $bot->form_number(3);
 # Enter the login credentials.
 $bot->field( email => '' );
 $bot->field( password => '' );
 $response = $bot->click();
 #print $response->decoded_content;
 $bot->get( 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/home?ie=UTF8&ref_=topnav_ys' );
 print $bot->content();


 $bot->post('https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/du/add-whitelist.html/ref=kinw_myk_wl_add', [sid => 'id', email=> 'v2@d.com']);
```

Data captured:

```
Host=www.amazon.com
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept=application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language=en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
DNT=1
Connection=keep-alive
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
Referer=https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk
Content-Length=39
Cookie=session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id
Pragma=no-cache
Cache-Control=no-cache
POSTDATA=sid=id&email=v%40d.com
```

Error Message-

```
Error POSTing https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/du/add-whitelist.html/ref=
kinw_myk_wl_add: InternalServerError at logon.pl line 81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`post` in `WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-post-).

```
$bot->post($url, [sid => 'id', email => 'v@d.com']);
```

Comment: It says internal server error.Have edited the question with the latest code.I removed the cookie length and id as i didnt know how to substitue cookie with values. Also what should the value of sid be. From  where would i get it in the program

Comment: You wrote `v2@d.com`, but should be `v@d.com`.

Comment: Just another email. The email is actually an input field. Any thing with @ and .com is accepted. Also how would i get the id dynamically from the program-In the post data i have substituted my id number simply with id. In reality it is an actual number.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer the question about the session id because I cannot actually run the program and look myself due to the lack of credentials. Get Amazon's permission to give out credentials for a test account.

Comment: I have a value but how do i substitute it dynamically in a program

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: The value of the session id is assigned and stored into a cookie. My question is whether there is any function which will give me that value so that i dont have to hard code it into my program as its value will be different every time i authenticate.

Comment: The WWW::Mechanize method `cookie_jar` returns a [HTTP::Cookies](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Cookies) object. Use its `scan` method to iterate over the cookies until you find the one you need.

Comment: print $bot->cookie_jar->as_string, $/; $cookie_jar->scan(sub { print "Cookie from ", $_[1], "\n" }); throws an error. I looked at the documentation but i didnt understand how to call the session-id. I also hard coded the value of session id. It still does not work

Comment: What error? - I'm growing tired of this. I have to pull every useful detail out of your nose because you are unwilling or unable to provide the full information so that I or anyone else who wants to help can see what you are doing there.

Comment: I had edited the question with the error.- Im sorry if im frustrating you but i just cant get this to work

Comment: I finally was able to get it working using hard coded values. Now i guess i need to know how to get the values in the cookie jar. Thanks anyway for the help.